What's the purpose of annotating "colla parte" in the piano accompaniment of a solo instrument?
I came across 2 mentions of colla parte in Adolf Huber's Student Concertino Op. 6 No. 2 for violin and piano (see score here) in page 3:

According to Oxford Companion to Music the meaning is

"With the part", "with the voice".  An indication to play another, written-out part, or to an accompanist to look to the main part for guidance on tempo, etc.

But as a sensitive accompanist to a solo instrument or to a vocalist, it is already my policy to do that.  Not only in tempo, but even mimicking the articulation, phrasing, and other minute nuances when the piano sometimes plays the primary part, similar to how the conductor works with the soloist when planning how to perform a concerto.
So I feel that the indication colla parte to be superfluous.  My question is: what does Huber mean by those 2 instances of colla parte here?  Do I miss something from the musical context?  More generally, how is colla parte being used?
For example, when hearing this performance starting at the first colla parte (minute 0:55) I can hear the pianist shaping the bass line like a second voice to the violin mimicking the phrasing and articulation.  Then in the second colla parte, the pianist does the same in doubling of the violin in the right hand.  Is that what Huber intended?  If so, wouldn't a good accompanist do that anyway, making the marking superfluous?

You're correct: the marking is completely superfluous.

I don’t know but I would assume the accompanist is meant to expect more expressive timing at those moments while other moments would be more in the meter and constant tempo. I’m used to seeing “colla voce” when there’s a fermata or other departure from a steady meter, which we don’t have explicitly here.

@ToddWilcox I see.  Maybe in this case Huber wants the accompanist to get out of accompanying mode and play that line like a second instrument, thus more prominent.  This is maybe in contrast with the 4th system in page 4, where the counter melody is NOT marked with colla parte, so in this case the piano shouldn't overshadow the violin.

Sometimes road signs warn drivers about pedestrians or deer crossing the road. You might encounter a pedestrian or deer in other places, and you're never supposed to hit them; the signs just alert you to heightened risk. The accompanist is always under the expectation "Don't lose the soloist"; colla parte just means "this material mirrors the soloist more closely, so you need extra attention to avoid obvious un-synchronization." Like the crossing signs, it's not a change in expectation (follow sensitively, as always) but alerting you to a change in the "terrain."
In the second colla parte section pictured, the piano's note values double the violin's exactly. In the first, this is true in the second measure. But the first colla parte is also a place where extra caution might be needed: it's a change from one section of the piece to another and a major change in texture and tone. The preceding material is quite energetic, with 16th notes and staccato, and the new section is lyrical, with longer note values and slurs. Given the genre and date, it's quite likely that the soloist would take a bit of time around the cadence and perhaps give the lyrical section a bit slower overall tempo. It's also likely that this "expressive" section might indulge in more rubato than the preceding "rhythmic" section.
One more reason that such seemingly obvious "warnings" might be added in this particular piece is that it's a "student" concerto. There's a very high probability that the accompanist is not a professional, but a violin teacher who can muddle through on piano, or a proud parent, or kind amateur volunteer. And student soloists can be even harder to follow! And rehearsal time may be limited or non-existent; even if it's "obvious" that these sections double (or sort-of-double) the violin, the sight-reading amateur might notice a moment too late.
Stepping away from the Huber—with the disclaimer that I'm a violinist, not a collaborative pianist—I would associate colla parte with more literal doubling. I encounter it sometimes in orchestral parts of cantatas, and read it as: "Sure, follow the conductor's beat as usual, but also direct some of your attention to the voice. (If it's choral, you even have to figure out which vocal part, and where in the room you're supposed to direct that attention!) Be aware of the text; shape your articulations to match its phonetics; and be aware of any ways that its meaning might impact the expression. Be ready to adjust your volume as you double, whether that means a little louder to bring out and support the line, or a little softer since you're doubling now instead of providing material."
I wouldn't normally expect a colla parte marking to tell me anything about what to play or what not to play, at least not as staff text within a score. I think the Oxford mention of "an indication to play another, written-out part" is more about its use in statements of instrumentation. E.g. you might find a piece scored for four vocal parts, with the notation "Con strumenti colla parte," meaning that instruments should double the voices throughout (or as seems best), reading from vocal parts or the score. If there is to be any connotation about instrumentation and playing something versus sitting out, I would expect it to apply to large sections like an aria or recit, not just stretches of a few bars.

I like your "deer crossing" sign analogy being applied to non-professional accompanist, or even to professional accompanist who is hired for the whole school end-of-semester recital where he/she might need to sight read all the accompanist parts.  Thanks also for the broader application of colla parte.

It’s letting the keyboardist know that the piano doubles the violin melody at that point. Without it, there might be some question on the keyboardist’s part on whether or not to play those notes.

Looking a bit more closely: it means that both piano and violin have "melodic lines" simultaneously and, as I interpret it, the piano should bring out that part to emphasize the duet. That better explains the first indication in the left-hand part.

Even without the marking there would be absolutely no doubt that that the pianist is expected to play that line.

@PiedPiper Well, absolutely no doubt for you, but I would certainly do a double-take when I suddenly noticed I was doubling the melody whereas I hadn't elsewhere in the piece. It also might cue me to adjust how I play that voice. It let's me know I should be watching the violinist for cues, especially if I'm absorbed in reading the keyboard part and not looking carefully the violin part at that moment.

@Aaron I see your point (about being absorbed in reading the keyboard part).  Maybe similar to the courtesy naturals / sharps / flats in a complex passage heavy with accidentals in the middle of modulation.  in Or might it be that in Huber's time, the pianist doesn't have the violin part alongside his part?  So it's a cue for the pianist to listen more closely to the violinist?

@GratefulDisciple I like your comparison to courtesy accidentals. Can’t speak to the part-writing, but Huber was 20th century.

Notation may be a hint, but it's still a reference that depends on many factors: we all know that there are occasions in which similar voice movements are not to be considered strictly as "unison". Even similar notes in different voices/instruments don't always mean they must be played all along together, and the fact that they have different octaves is a possible case of questioning. Yes, they would be normally and instinctively played along, but that's not an absolute rule (consider the case of solo concerts or Opera). The specification means that the player is expected to play along.
